# read only error while reading data from excel in python

Tags: python, excel

I am new to python.

I have written a sample code to read data from excel in python.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'names.xlsx', use_iterators = True)

for sheet in wb.get_sheet_names():
    worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name=sheet)
    print sheet

    if worksheet:
        index = 2
        append_brace = False

        while True:
            gender_index = 'B' + str(index)
            operator_index = 'C' + str(index)
            name_index = 'D' + str(index)
            lastname_index = 'E' + str(index)
            middlename_index = 'F' + str(index)

            print gender_index,"\n"
            print worksheet[gender_index]
            index = index+1;
```

when I run this file,the gender_index(cell) is getting printed properly but could not print the cell value.

Following is the error I have seen.

```
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x10faece30>
```

Comment: Whenever you report errors, you should include the whole traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` to read excel files, your life will be much easier.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('names.xlsx', sheetname=sheetname)
```

Then for printing columns you can do:

```
print df[column_name]
```

where `column_name` is the column name in Excel.